# Running multiple SpringBoot application classes from a single FAT jar

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a FAT jar which contains multiple classes annotated with @SpringBootApplication. In spring boot is there any way to launch multiple spring boot classes from a single FAT jar?
Can it be done using profiles?